# Laravel Notification Broadcast with different guard

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

So I have a laravel application with two guards, admin and users. I'm trying to send notifications in real time using pusher. I'm trying to notify only the admin guards ( Because only they have access to the admin panel )

Here's my Broadcast service Provider:

```
 public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes([
            'middleware' => ['admin'],
            'guard' => 'admin',
            'prefix' => 'admin',
        ]);


        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

My channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Admin.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int)$user->id === (int)$id;
}, ['guards' => ['admin']]);
```

My notification is just a simple laravel notification that implements ShouldQueue.

My Echo configuration and channel:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    authEndpoint: '/admin/broadcasting/auth',
});



let userId = document.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').getAttribute('content');
window.Echo.private('App.Models.Admin.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
    });
```

My notification arrives to the pusher dashboard, but it doesn't log in my browser.

[image]